# ¿como crear un objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo en JavaScript y estoy intentando desarrollar un formulario que solicite nombre, edad y dni, con estos datos crear un objeto, el cual lo debo guardar en un array para posteriormente listar los cuando se presione un botón.

Comment: Cabe aclarar que el formulario ya lo tengo hecho me falta la parte de crear el objeto y guardarlo en un array y listar los datos

Comment: Que has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un objeto puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};
```

Estos pares 'clave:valor' son las propiedades del objeto. Luego puedes agregarlos a un array. Te recomiendo empezar por acá, es bastante claro [JavaScript Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Comment: Cabe senalar que basta con `var person = {}` para crear el objeto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ni idea que eso se podía, muchas gracias